# How do I know if a string is contained within the another?

Tags: c, string, compare

Say, the user inputted a string in my program, and I want my program to compare *only a certain part of the string* with a string that I already have. For example:

**User inputted:** "Hello I'm doing great".

**The string part I want to find** is "doing great".

Is there any specific way or function in C programming language that'll help me to do so?

Comment: The standard library function `strstr` can do this.

Comment: You should really edit your question and its title in order to clarify (also to yourself) what you need. You don't want to "compare only a part of a string with another string", because this suggests that you already know which part you want to compare. What you want is to find *if* a string is contained within another, and if it is where it is.

Comment: Learning a new language and its environment includes reading a lot of documentation. A good beginner's C book or the standard is helpful, also here.

Comment: If you cannot manage to use the function suggested by @SteveSummit, edit your question and provide a [mcve]. Writing it is a good way to learn the language.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
char your_sentence[512] = "Hello I'm doing great";
char looking_for[256]= "doing great";
char *result = strstr(your_sentence, looking_for);
if(result != NULL)
    printf(result);
else
    printf("not found!");
```

please choose proper length for your strings!

Comment: "please choose proper length for your strings!" --> Let the compiler do it with `char your_sentence[/*nothing here*/] = "Hello I'm doing great";`

Answer (score 0):

,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char user_input[1000];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",user_input);
   
    char search[] = "doing great";
    char *ptr = strstr(user_input, search);

    if (ptr != NULL) /* Substring found */
        {
        printf("'%s' contains '%s'\n", user_input, search);
        }
        else /* Substring not found */
        {
            printf("'%s' doesn't contain '%s'\n", user_input, search);
        }

    

return 0;
```

}